# An error occurred while following creat-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to solve these errors quickly and study. But the search continues and the symptoms continue to appear even though others have tried to do so.

```
> hello-react@0.1.0 start /Users/kimseungwon/hello-react
> react-scripts start

> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! hello-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kimseungwon/.npm/_logs/2018-09-02T08_28_05_806Z-debug.log
```

> node version: 8.11.4 
>   npm version: 5.6.0

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hello! Try run with admin rights and post the debug.log

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run the project with react-scripts command, just you should using the npm command as below as you can see in package.json scripts object:

```
npm run start
```